# Reset ActiveX Option Button in Excel

Tags: excel, activex

I am in Excel 2016 working with ActiveX option buttons:
[My project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATfiN.png)

I need to reset the option buttons so that neither option, "Yes - Need It" and No - And Do Not Need It" are selected.